# In need your help for a simple javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get a specific class with javascript.
This class is bootstrap's grid : col-md-8

I need to get the number, I try this :

```
$class = $('div').attr('class');
$number = $class.match(/^col-md-./);
```

I'm real beginner in regex, please help me.

EDIT : $class may have more class like : 'col col-md-8 col-offset-md-8'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\d+` as pattern.

```
'col-md-8'.match(/\d+/)
// => ["8"]
'col-md-8'.match(/\d+/)[0]
// => "8"
```

- `\d` match a digit character.
- `+` is repetition modifier: makes previous pattern to match multiple (1 or more) times

---

**UPDATE** response to the the comment:

Using capturing group:

```
'other-class-1 col-md-8'.match(/col-md-(\d+)/)[1]
// => "8"
```

Comment: It works when only one class, but I forgot to mention that I could have more.

Comment: I need to pass a variable in string 'col-md' and now doesn't work.
I hate regex :/

Comment: @dmassiani, Try `var prefix = 'col-md'; 'other-class-1 col-md-8'.match(new RegExp(prefix + '-(\\d+)'))[1]
"8"`

Answer (score 1):

Use simply this: $class.substr(7)

Answer (score 1):

You can mix falsetru's answer with your answer to ignore the other classees and numbers:

```
cls = 'col-md-8'col-md-8
match = cls.match(/col-md-(\d+)/)
// => ['col-md-8', '8']
```

The parenthesis capture substrings of the total pattern and store them in the match array. The first element of the match array is the full matched patter and the remaining elements are the individual captures.

```
match[1]
// => "8"
```

To convert a string to an integer you can use the unary plus operator:

```
+match[1]
// => 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will work as you want

```
    /class="(.)*col-md-\d*"/g
```

Here is the [example]: http://jsfiddle.net/s74chw8k/13/